# Have at least 5 valid names in Scan and introduce "end" to end the program - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

My project is to ask the user to introduce up to 10 full names with up to 120 characters and at least two names with at least 4 characters. If the user reaches at least 5 valid names could introduce "end" to end the program, how do I would do it? (Note: The program needs to end if it reaches 10 names.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter up to 10 full names with up to 120 characters and at least two names with at least 4 characters:");
    String fullName;
    String[] SeparatedName;
    int i = 0;

    do {
        fullName= keyboard.nextLine();
        i++;

        SeparatedName=  fullName.split(" "); 
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SeparatedName));

        int l = 0; 
        for(int n = 0; n < SeparatedName.length; n++){
            if(SeparatedName[n].length() >= 4 ) {
                l++;
            }
        }

        if(l >= 2 && fullName.length() <= 120 || fullName.equalsIgnoreCase("end") ) {
            //valid name
            System.out.println("'" +fullName+ "'" + " is valid");
        }
        else {System.out.println("'" +fullName+ "'" + " is invalid");}

    }
    while(!fullName.equalsIgnoreCase("end") || i<10);

    keyboard.close();
}
```

Output (doesnt end):

```
aaaa aaaa
'aaaa aaaa' is valid
aaa aa
'aaa aa' is invalid  
aaaa aaaa
'aaaa aaaa' is valid
aaaa aaaa
'aaaa aaaa' is valid
aaaaaaa aaaaaa
'aaaaaaa aaaaaa' is valid
end
'end' is valid
```

When the user introduced end should stop because it has already 5 valid names. If it reaches 10 full names should stop and it doesn't.

Comment: And about "If the user reaches at least 5 valid names could introduce "end" to end the program, how do I would do it?"?

Comment: That is an error *

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not exiting the main method when your exit requirements are met. You can exit a method by using the `return;` keyword.

So add a if statement before the condition to the Do-While and change the loop condition to true, like this:

```
if(fullName.equalsIgnoreCase("end") || i>=10){
keyboard.close();
return;
}
while(true);
```

This way your method will exit when the exit requirements are met.

Comment: If I did that i couldnt have keyboard.close()

Comment: @Ruca I added in the keyboard.close() method call

Answer (score 0):

In the place of

```
    if(l >= 2 && fullName.length() <= 120 || fullName.equalsIgnoreCase("end") ) {
        //valid name
        System.out.println("'" +fullName+ "'" + " is valid");
    }
    else {System.out.println("'" +fullName+ "'" + " is invalid");}
```

condition in your code, I think the following `if-elseif-else` condition addresses your needs better

```
if (fullName.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
    break; // exits the do while loop
} else if (l >= 2 && fullName.length() <= 120 ) {
    //valid name
    System.out.println("'" +fullName+ "'" + " is valid");
} else {
   System.out.println("'" +fullName+ "'" + " is invalid");
}
```