# Enter up to 10 valid names in scan - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to ask the user to enter up to 10 valid names. In my code I have to have a array with all the full names. Inside that array the full names are a array with the names separated. For each full name - To be valid needs to have at least two names with at least 4 characters. If the user introduces 5 valid full names could digit "fim" to end the program. The max is 10 valid full names, if the user reaches the 10 valid full names the program should end. These code isn't correct because it doesnt end when it reaches 10 valid full names or if the user digits end after 5 or more valid full names.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter up to 10 full names with up to 120 characters and at least two names with at least 4 characters: ");
    String[] fullName= new String[10];
    String[] separatedName;
    String name;
    int i = 0;

    do {
        name = keyboard.nextLine();
        fullName[i]=name;
        i++;

        separatedName =  name.split(" "); 
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(separatedName));

        int l = 0; 
        for(int n = 0; n < separatedName .length; n++){
            if(separatedName [n].length() >= 4 ) {
                l++;
            }
        }
        if(l >= 2 && name.length() <= 120 || name.equalsIgnoreCase("fim") ) {
            //System.out.println("Valid name.");
        }
        else {System.out.println("'" +name+ "'" + " is an invalid name");
        }

    }
    while(i<10);

    keyboard.close();
}
```

Comment: what is your question/problem ?

Comment: I added why it isnt working

Comment: And the elements of fullName[] could only have the valid names by the condition  if(l >= 2 && name.length() <= 120 || name.equalsIgnoreCase("fim") )

Comment: Can you show outputs and explain why they are wrong. Sometimes explaining the problem fixes it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have at least 5 valid names in Scan and introduce "end" to end the program - JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434923/have-at-least-5-valid-names-in-scan-and-introduce-end-to-end-the-program-jav)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still Not sure what you are trying to do. Try this and this should solve your problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter up to 10 full names with up to 120 characters and at least two names with at least 4 characters: ");
        String[] fullName= new String[10];
        String[] separatedName;
        String name;
        int i = 0;
        int validCount=0;

        do {
            name = keyboard.nextLine();
            fullName[i]=name;
            i++;

            separatedName =  name.split(" "); 
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(separatedName));

            int l = 0; 
            for(int n = 0; n < separatedName .length; n++){
                if(separatedName [n].length() >= 4 ) {
                    l++;
                }
            }
            if(l >= 2 && name.length() <= 120  ) {
                validCount++;
                //System.out.println("Valid name.");
            }
            else {System.out.println("'" +name+ "'" + " is an invalid name");
            }

            if(validCount>=5 || name.equalsIgnoreCase("fim")) {
                break;
            }

        }
        while(i<10);

        keyboard.close();
    }
```